# Formulating a binary sequence with shift in MILP

Tags: constraint-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I would like to know if it's actually possible to encode a (binary) sequence with rotations in MILP/MIP.

Given a binary sequence (0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1) and variables x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7, 
I want to restrict my MILP program such that it takes up one of the following:

(x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7) = (0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1) or
(x7,x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6) = (0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1) or
...
(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x0) = (0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)

I understand that the rotation can be easily solved by just extending the sequence. But I find myself creating multiple MILP instances, each instance corresponding to exactly one of the cases. If this is infeasible, why?

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches one could design and it's not really clear in what context you will use it.

Here is a relatively simple one:

```
A: Introduce n new binary variables: These describe the "root / first zero" decision

    s_x0, s_x1, s_x2, s_x3, s_x4, s_x5, s_x6, s_x7

B: Add a simplex-constraint / make those add up to 1: We do want a unique root!

    s_x0 + s_x1 + s_x2 + s_x3 + s_x4 + s_x5 + s_x6 + s_x7 = 1

C: Encode all implications for all possible roots which can be chosen

  for: s_x0  

    logic-form   |  milp-form

    s_x0 ->  x0    (1-s_x0) + x0     >= 1
    s_x0 ->  x1    (1-s_x0) + x1     >= 1
    s_x0 -> !x2    (1-s_x0) + (1-x2) >= 1
    s_x0 -> !x3    (1-s_x0) + (1-x3) >= 1
    s_x0 -> !x4    (1-s_x0) + (1-x4) >= 1
    s_x0 -> !x5    (1-s_x0) + (1-x5) >= 1
    s_x0 ->  x6    (1-s_x0) + x6     >= 1
    s_x0 -> !x7    (1-s_x0) + (1-x7) >= 1

  for: s_x1

    s_x1 -> !x0    (1-s_x1) + (1-x0) >= 1
    s_x1 ->  x1    (1-s_x1) + x1     >= 1
    s_x1 ->  x2    (1-s_x1) + x2     >= 1
    s_x1 -> !x3    (1-s_x1) + (1-x3) >= 1
    s_x1 -> !x4    (1-s_x1) + (1-x4) >= 1
    s_x1 -> !x5    (1-s_x1) + (1-x5) >= 1
    s_x1 -> !x6    (1-s_x1) + (1-x6) >= 1
    s_x1 ->  x7    (1-s_x1) + x7     >= 1

  for ......
```

This:

- Basically exploits the core structure behind the problem:

  - We need to chose between n different patterns and must enforce the effects
- Will get big (at least for human-consumption)
- Is rather simple / easy to understand and implement
- **But also should provide a nice LP-relaxation**
- **This (non-compact) formulation also exploits some strengths of MILP-solvers (e.g. clique-tables)**

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I am surprised I have totally missed such a simple solution.